# In how many ways can a group of $n$ people composed of six types be created with restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we need to create a group of $n \geq 20$ people with the following
types and requirements:

- Scientists, at least 2;
- Pro Athletes, at least 1;
- Mathematicians, at least 5;
- Plumbers, at least 0;
- Botanists, at least 3;
- Astronauts, at least 4;

How many possibilities are there? Assume that people of the same profession are not distinguishable.

I'm really confused how to approach this problem. Any ideas?

Side note: the answer has to be expressed in terms of n.

Comment: You should begin by looking at binomial probability to take care of the _at least_ problem.

Comment: @Rhendz  This is a [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem, not a binomial probability problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using generating functions, we have

$ \displaystyle g(x)=(x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots)(x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)(x^5+x^6+x^7+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)$

$\hspace{.48 in}(x^3+x^4+x^5+\cdots)(x^4+x^5+x^6+\cdots)$

$\hspace{.3 in}\displaystyle=x^{15}(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^6=x^{15}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-x)^6}=x^{15}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+5}{5}x^m=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+5}{5}x^{m+15}$,

so the coefficient of $x^n$ is given by $\dbinom{n-10}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since we only care about how many people there are of each type, this is a [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem.  Let $x_1$ denote the number of scientists, $x_2$ denote the number of pro athletes, $x_3$ denote the number of mathematicians; $x_4$ denote the number of plumbers, $x_5$ denote the number of botanists, and $x_6$ denote the number of astronauts.  Then the number of ways of forming the group is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = n \tag{1}$$
in the integers subject to the restrictions that $x_1 \geq 2$, $x_2 \geq 1$, $x_3 \geq 5$, $x_4 \geq 0$, $x_5 \geq 3$, and $x_6 \geq 4$.  The restrictions can be handled by introducing the variables
\begin{align*}
y_1 & = x_1 - 2\\
y_2 & = x_2 - 1\\
y_3 & = x_3 - 5\\
y_4 & = x_4\\
y_5 & = x_5 - 3\\
y_6 & = x_6 - 4
\end{align*}
Substituting $y_1 + 2$ for $x_1$, $y_2 + 1$ for $x_2$, $y_3 + 5$ for $x_3$, $y_4$ for $x_4$, $y_5 + 3$ for $x_5$, and $y_6 + 4$ for $x_4$ yields 
$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 + y_6 = n - 15 \tag{2}$$
Equation 2 is an equation in the non-negative integers. A particular solution corresponds to the placement of five addition signs in a row of $n - 15$ ones.  For instance, if $n = 25$, then 
$$1 1 + 1 + + 1 1 + 1 + 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $y_1 = 2$, $y_2 = 1$, $y_3 = 0$, $y_4 = 2$, $y_5 = 1$, $y_6 = 4$.  The number of such solutions is
$$\binom{n - 15 + 5}{5} = \binom{n - 10}{5}$$
since we must choose which $5$ of the $n - 10$ symbols ($n - 15$ ones and $5$ addition signs) will be addition signs.

Answer (score 1):

Place the minimum requirements of each category at the start.

Now you need $(n-15)$ total in any which way from the $6$ categories.

Using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), the required answer $= \dbinom{(n-15)+6-1}{6-1}= \dbinom{n-10}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Inclusion-Exclusion and complementary counting.